Reopen request 55269
The question "Interpreting "Juge-moi" is closed as needing details of clarity.
I am really angry that my recent edits have not been successful in reopening the question.
So, I am waiting for a satisfactory edit to reopen this question. How to get this re-opened?
I have asked this question on October 29 when the French site is the Today's Featured Site. Look at the similar question from the Latin site. The original version of the question came as an attempt to mimic that question from the Latin site.
I received the following comments on the question and I kept making one edit after receiving each comment:

Can you provide more context? This line seems unknown to gallica.bnf.fr and other.


Your edit doesn't help in anyway to answer your original question. You must give the context of your original quote. Your "source" links to Madame Bovary (19th century novel, not medieval) and the line you quote is not in Madame Bovary. We need a full context, what comes before and if necessary after the sentence, with exact punctuation.

Then the moderator closes the question with the comment:

I've closed the question for now; there are some attempts to answer in the comments but we can't be any more specific without the (real) source where you found this. Other material can be found in the link to the related question; there is no need to duplicate it here. If you return and edit or comment, we can reopen and proceed from there. Hope this has been helpful.

I kept on making more edits to get the question reopened, and then when there was no source found for the quote:

Juge-moi le cygne et laisse le bavardage céder la place à l'hirondelle
, I changed the quote to a quote from Bible Study Tools.

Then I received a comment saying:

The question deserves to be removed because the original one dealt with a colloquial grammar point, whereas this one is straight, formal imperative.

Then I once again changed the quote.
Then I received the following comments:

I do not understand your revised question. It seems self-contradictory. You say you don't see any indication in Wiktionary that "juge" is a valid imperative form (we pointed this out to you in the comments), and later you say that "juge" is the imperative form of the verb "juger," which means "to judge." And French has no ablative case, so I don't know why you say that "Wiktionary only shows a reference to the ablative." If you want us to reopen the question, please formulate it so it's comprehensible and not self-contradictory.


What kind of answer are you expecting with your revised question? That your proposed translation is the correct interpretation of the French sentence? It is. What problem are you at grips with? As far as I can read, none at all: VTC until you've expressed >= 1. FYI, this (meaning the lack of an explicit problem statement) is the lack of detail + clarity which makes the question useless and prompted its close-down.

After that, I have spent the last week making more edits with the question, but I am angry that my edits are not helping to reopen the question. Can you suggest any edit that will reopen the question?

May I say that taking a question that was about a Latin medieval quote, translating the quote (incompetently) into French, and asking about it on French.SE is not what this site was intended for. Further, changing the question to something that bears almost no resemblance to the original question before asking to reopen it is not the intended purpose of editing and reopening questions. At this point, I don't believe any edit will help you reopen the question.

It's obvious from your editing efforts you want the question reopened; it is equally obvious (to the community; it need not be to you) none of your additions make your question any more useful. Hence the downvotes (which are about your revised question) and the votes not to reopen.
You quoted my comment; what did you understand of it? All the edits you made later were to detail your interpretation of the French sentence, as if it needed any. I stand by my comment: it does not. It is fine as it is. I see nothing we might add to it. For all we know, YOU HAVE GIVEN A FINE ANSWER TO YOUR OWN QUESTION, and I'd add (if you will pardon my French): yes you have, for X.*st'ssake.
If you want answers to your (revised) question, then give us relevant detail, e. g. the one I requested from you in my comment: explain what you feel is wrong with the interpretation you provided. If nothing, great! The question was pointless: you solved your problem all by yourself. Instead of calling for answers, just delete it and move on.
